# Is a Reform convert considered not-Jewish or safek Jewish?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, safek, lifnei-iver, reform-judaism

I am basing this question on something I read somewhere: that a non-Jew is able to accept the Torah and obligate himself in mitzvot independent of the bet din (court) conversion procedure. A non-Jew can even be ignorant of the contents of the Torah and do this. Since he has not gone through our procedure, however, we do not accept him as a Jew until he has done so.

Nonetheless, if I have a Reform convert as a guest (who doesn't keep kosher), may I serve him ham (ignoring moris ayin etc.)?

Is my premise correct?

Comment: I don't know where you got your first idea from, unless you're just being imprecise. A non-Jew cannot "obligate" himself independent of a Beis Din, but he can "perform" mitzvos, and possibly get reward for doing so (see Teshuvos HaRambam Pe'er Hador no. 60 and in his commentary to Terumos 3:9). It has to do with the actual question though (which I think is a good one, if you just take the title)

Comment: It may depend on the details. IOW, how "reform" was the conversion? Did he get a Bris? Did they use a kosher Mikva? Did they ask him to accept the yoke of Mitzvos? Did he know what that means? Did he plan on really accepting? Or did they simply dunk him in a pool and sing Hava NaGila?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Reform conversions involve reform Rabbis.  They don't bring in Shomrei Shabbos to be the eidim. Ger tzarich shlosha.

Comment: @YeZ - all part of the equation. Check if any Shomer Shabbos Jews were in attendance. (Worse than Kiddushin where you need a "Witness" - here maybe you only need their presence.